# Can I make a qr code generator app that contains user information?

Tags: qr-code

I want to create an app that makes QR code that contains user's information.

The current scenario is that after sns log into the app, make QR code that contains user's account information

After that, I would like to create a QR code generator app that allows the user's information to be sent along with the QR code when User scan to QR code scanner.

What I'm curious about right now is whether I can make a QR code that contains the account information for that user, and if I can, what modules I can use to create.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7273).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup, it's completely possible.

[Zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing), library ( Java ) can be used to generate as well as decode the QR code.

Some relevant tutorials are :

1. [Java QR Code Generator](https://www.journaldev.com/470/java-qr-code-generator-zxing-example)
2. [Reading QR code](https://www.spaceotechnologies.com/qr-code-android-using-zxing-library/)